# OpenStack re-deploy only one instance from a stack

Tags: openstack

newbie here. I'm doing some tests from my personal OpenStack environment and I succesfully deployed a basic stack contains 2 instances.

```
openstack stack create --template heat_vnf.yaml StackTest
```

Now, because I have to do it in my office environment, I'm trying to re-deploy only one instance. So, delete one instance, and re-deploy it without touch the other one.
I know that this is possibile because my colleague already did it, unfortunately he left the company so I can't ask him how he did it in the past.

Could someone advice on how I can re-deploy one instance from stack without destroy the whole stack and start from scratch?

I tried to delete one instance and then:

```
openstack stack update --template heat_vnf.yaml StackTest
```

But this will not re-deploy the deleted instance

Thank you
Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody knows? :)
Ok, I leave my tested solution for who need in future to re-deploy only one instance from stack leaving untouched the others.

```
openstack server rebuild [VM_ID]
```

This will rebuild from scratch the VM keeping its original configuration, e.g. nova port, ip addresses, flavour, and so on.

Comment: If this is a valid answer can you please mark it as such? The 2 days waiting period is over.